# How to disable plugin vue.fullpage on media query in nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a problem. How to disable plugin vue.fullpage on media query in nuxt.js?
**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
     '~plugins/fullpage-vue.js'
  }
}
```

**fullpage-vue.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import 'animate.css'
import 'fullpage-vue/src/fullpage.css'
import VueFullpage from 'fullpage-vue'

if (screen && screen.width > 768) {
   Vue.use(VueFullpage)
}
```

So does not work. 
error: screen a not defined

Comment: If you make use of [the official fullPage.js component for Vue.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/vue-fullpage/) then you can use the responsive options.

Answer (score 1):

It's help me.

```
if (screen.width > 768) {
    Vue.use(VueFullpage)
    console.log('fullPage init')
}
```

Or **maybe** if you need SSR use

```
if (process.browser) {
    if (screen.width > 768) {
        Vue.use(VueFullpage)
        console.log('fullPage init')
    }
}
```

But the better idea is really use [official vullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/vue-fullpage/) which was released on January 2018.